# Dynamic scrolling / scrollspy background?

Tags: dynamic, background, scroll

This effect of a dynamic scrolling background which scrolls at a different rate than the page content is extensively used by The Clymb in their feature stories. I've seen the same effect used in some news articles on other sites too. But here are some examples of the effect I would like to copy:

http://www.theclymb.com/stories/featured-stories/under-the-midnight-sun/

(Each of their articles use this effect, but I am limited on how many links I can post here)

I first saw this effect used in this mind blowing article:

http://www.nytimes.com/projects/2012/snow-fall/#/?part=tunnel-creek

Apple did something similar (but not the same) for the New Mac Pro.

Before I try to reinvent the wheel, does anybody know of an article or reference I could be directed to - to learn the process on how this effect is done?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a showcase for a jQuery plugin that does exactly what you're looking for:  http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrolldeck.js/decks/parallax/

Here's the direct link to the plugin: https://github.com/IanLunn/jQuery-Parallax

Comment: No problem.  If this is what you were looking for, I'd appreciate you marking it as the answer.  Thanks!